# 500 error when trying to update room topic

Tags: bug, chat, 500-server-error

I've noticed an issue which I've seen a couple of weeks back and thought it was a one off, but I've just tried to do it again and it's the same problem. When trying to update the room topic for the C# StackOverflow chat (7) of which I am an RO, the request fails and sends me to the 500 error page.

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the message. It seems to be that I can't save at all, regardless of if I change the topic (as I was trying to this time) or even just the tags (which is what I tried last time)

I've reproduced this error on multiple browsers (Chrome & firefox) and different PCs, so I'm reasonably certain it's not my end.

Comment: @rene probably something is wrong with the existing room info, so it's room-specific.

Comment: hmm.... tried now to reproduce by changing test room info to be same as the C#, no error. Can other room owners change the room topic? Might be issue with your own chat profile or permissions.

Comment: I've asked another RO to have a go and he's failed too. Come in and have a go if you like https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: I can repro if I add a tag and leave the tag drop down open: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW4tj.png saving in thiis condition gives me a 500. If I enter an extra space, so the drop down is dismissed and then press save, my change is commited.

Comment: Odd, I tried leaving an extra space after the list disappears and it's still broken for me.